# Adding permissions to a project

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception

But I see this

```
$ gcloud container clusters create inception-serving-cluster --num-nodes 5
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.create" permission for "projects/tensorflow-serving".
```

I did not see an option to add permissions to the project anywhere. How do I do this using the CLI or the UI?

EDIT:
I do have the project created
[image]

EDIT:
Just saw that it works fine from the cloud shell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: Your project's name is `tensorflow-serving-1360`, so you should be running `gcloud container clusters create inception-serving-cluster --num-nodes 5 --project=tensorflow-serving-1360`.

---

The project `tensorflow-serving` is not owned by you. It is the example project name used in the linked tutorial, but you need to replace it with the name of your own project as described in the line at the beginning of Part 2:

> Here we assume you have created and logged in a [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) project named
>   `tensorflow-serving`

Comment: Thanks, but I do have the project created. Attached an image now. Still getting the error.

Comment: Have you enabled the container engine API? In the cloud console, if you click on the container engine tab it will enable it automatically.

Comment: I did do that too. I can create a cluster from the web UI but not from the CLI.

Comment: I just realized that it works from the cloud shell. Shouldn't it work from my laptop too then?

Comment: Are you using the same account through the UI/CloudShell as you are in the CLI? (You can run `gcloud auth list` to see what account is active).

Comment: Yes, I'm on the same account in both cases. I can post a screenshot if needed.

Comment: `tensorflow-serving` is the "display" name of your project, but the friendly names don't need to be unique and can't be used from the command line to run commands. You must use the unique project id, which in your case in `tensorflow-serving-1360`. This explains why it works in the cloud shell (which sets the project environment variable for you correctly). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Tested on 2019.04.07)

1. Firstly, check the list of auth accounts:

   ```
   gcloud auth list
   ```
2. Next set the active account:

   ```
   gcloud config set account <email_address_from_above_output>
   ```
3. Then, specify the parameter for create cluster commamd:

   ```
   gcloud container clusters create <cluster_name> --num-nodes=2 --project=<PROJECT_ID>

   e.g.
   gcloud container clusters create prod-myapp-cluster --num-nodes=2 --project=myapp-20394823094
   ```

   Expected output:

   ```
   kubeconfig entry generated for prod-myapp-cluster.
   NAME                LOCATION       MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP       MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION   NUM_NODES  STATUS
   prod-myapp-cluster  asia-south1-a  1.11.7-gke.12   35.5xx.2xx.1xx  n1-standard-1  1.11.7-gke.12  2          RUNNING
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your project name or create a project if you have created on already at console.cloud.google.com
2. Enable Kubernetes engine API on the console
3. run this code on your command prompt

```
gcloud container clusters create bd-serving-cluster --num-nodes 5 -project=tensorflow-serving-264611 \
```

```
--zone=us-central1-f
```

4. replace 'bd' with the name of your serving cluster and 'tensorflow-serving-264611' with the project name you created in step 1 and you can choose your preferred zone or use the default 'us-central1-f'

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the "IAM" console, choose the "Grant Access" button and assign to the executing user the "Kubernetes Engine Admin" and "Service Account User" role. The later might be only needed for the cluster auto mode where nodes are automatically created.

Note, that this permission are not very fine grained and other roles or more fine grained permissions would better suite maybe your project.